# Factorial simplification help; how did wolfram get this?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, factorial

in this problem n is assumed to be odd:
Here's what I am trying to simplify:
$$ \frac {(n-2)!( \frac {n-1}{2})!} { (n-1)! (\frac {n-3} {2}) !}
$$

Wolfram is telling me that this should simplify to $$\frac {1}{2} $$ but I am very confused about how it gets there. I understand that the two factorial terms combine, but then I have $$ (n-2) (\frac {n-1} {2}) $$ as my final simplification and I really have no idea how to move from that to $$\frac{1}{2}$$ Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't ( (n-1)/2) !  become   (n-1)/2  * (n-2)/2  * (n-3) /2 .... * 0 /2
where n changes by 1 instead of by 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that

$$\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-1)!} = \frac{(n-2)(n-3)(n-4) \cdots (2)(1)}{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4) \cdots (2)(1)} = \frac{1}{n-1}$$

Similarly, notice that

$$\dfrac{ \left( \dfrac{n-1}{2} \right)! }{\left( \dfrac{n-3}{2} \right)!} = \dfrac{ \left( \dfrac{n-1}{2} \right)\left( \dfrac{n-3}{2} \right)\left( \dfrac{n-5}{2} \right)\cdots(2)(1) }{\left( \dfrac{n-3}{2} \right)\left( \dfrac{n-5}{2} \right)\cdots(2)(1) } = \frac{n-1}{2}$$

Multiply the two together for the desired result.

Comment: Thank you! That makes quite a bit more sense than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation based upon the *[functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Factorial_of_non-integer_values)*: $n!=n(n-1)!$.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac {(n-2)!( \frac {n-1}{2})!} { (n-1)! (\frac {n-3} {2}) !}}
> &=\frac {(n-2)!}{(n-1)(n-2)!}\cdot \frac {\frac{n-1}{2}\left(\frac{n-3}{2}\right)!}{\left(\frac{n-3}{2}\right)!}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n-1}\cdot\frac{n-1}{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.